# dracut and separate /usr?

Tags: linux, gentoo, initramfs

I would like to use *systemd* on my Gentoo box. Unfortunately, I have `/usr` on a separate partition and Gentoo puts `libdbus` into `/usr/lib`, leading to a segfault on boot, since systemd relies on dbus.

Hence I would like to generate an initramfs using *dracut* that mounts `/usr` for me. This partition is on an md raid. I think that I have setup dracut correctly to include mdadm, but somehow it does not mount `/usr`

I think that it is configured to only mount the root partition by default, even if it detects other partitions.

How can I tell *dracut* to mount `/usr` also before switching to the real init?

Comment: Just curios, Is there a good reason to put /usr on a separate partition?

Comment: Not in my case, no. It's just that it is a bit complicated to change this in the current setup, and I thought that creating an initramfs using dracut would be a simple task that solved the problem until I manage to repartition the machine.

Answer (score 1):

I may have found a solution by digging through a lot of forums. For a cross-distribution framework, documentation certainly is scarce.

There is a dracut-module called `fstab-sys`, which reads `/etc/fstab.sys` and mounts all partitions mentioned there. The format is the same as the one of `/etc/fstab`.

To sum up, I had to create `/etc/fstab.sys` containing `/usr/` and create the dracut image with something like

```
dracut -a fstab-sys --mdadmconf -H "" <kernel_version>
```

**Warning:** I could not test this yet. I will remove this warning once this is verified.

Comment: Unfortunately, I could not verify this yet, since I seem to have problems with the mdraid module also..

Comment: It does not work. But it might be a dracut bug, since I am fairly sure this is how it is supposed to be...

Answer (score 1):

From dracut-012 [NEWS](https://git.kernel.org/?p=boot/dracut/dracut.git;a=blob;f=NEWS;h=ba92c140188550b1ac89a17203b3839d20af1030;hb=ac965cd8289572f4786c8c6f95a6c05dea29936d):

```
 ...
 8 - try to mount /usr, if init points to a path in /usr
 ...
```

Comment: Thank you, that is indeed interesting but will not help, since systemd is at `/bin/systemd`, it just uses `libdbus` which is in `/usr/lib`.